# Data stored in cache is null (Cache driver: array)

Tags: caching, laravel-5.6

I tried to store data in cached but when I retrieved the cached it returns null.

My cache driver is `CACHE_DRIVER=array`

and here is my controller...

```
    public function index(Request $request){
        view()->share('page_sub', 'Webhhook');

        $data = Cache::get('repo');
        dd($data);

        return view('webhook.index', compact('data'));
    }



    public function handle(Request $request){

        // $data = $request;

        $admins = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){$q->whereIn('roles.name', ['superadmin']);})->get();

        $data = [
            'id' => $request['repository']['id'],
            'name' => $request['repository']['name'],
            'tags_url' => $request['repository']['tags_url'],
            'archive_url' => $request['repository']['archive_url'],
            'updated_at' => $request['repository']['updated_at'],
        ];

        $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

        $repo_data = cache('repo');

        \Log::info($repo_data);

        if ($data['updated_at'] != $repo_data['updated_at']) {
            Cache::put('repo', $data, $now->addMonth(1));
        }

        foreach($admins as $user){
            $user->notify(new  WebhookNotification($repo_data));
        }
    }
```

when I `dd($data)` from this `$data = Cache::get('repo');` the result is `null`

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`CACHE_DRIVER=array` only stores data in cache for functions used in same request and expires as soon as response is sent to browser.

If you want to access cache data in multiple request you can use `CACHE_DRIVER=file` this will save your data in files which can be accessed later.